# Broadband internet connection problem on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, broadband

I am using a broadband internet connection from a local ISP. I installed Ubuntu 11.10 yesterday but I could not configure my internet connection like I did on 10.04 before. On 10.04, it was easy to configure and connect to internet. Generally, I used DSL settings to configure my net. There I enter my user name, my connection's name and password to connect with net. But now in 11.10 it's not working. What can I do to connect it perfectly?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with Ubuntu 11.10 and wireless connection speed. The problem lies with 11.10's inability to deal with the "n" standard that most new routers use. The temporary ( I hope) workaround is to simply go to your router's settings page and disable the "n" connection speed. Hope this solves your issue, took me the better part of a day (and more than a little swearing ) to figure it out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to re-enable n support with the following commands

```
rmmod iwlagn
modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=0
```

*Harry*